# How to shift down columns row and re-assign column values in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = 'filename.dat'
df = pd.read_table(data)
print(df)

   0.098722  08l23252 243434214  5         True
0  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  2         True
1  0.283421  1.224234  7.823421  2         False
2 -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  4         False
3      2.34     0.271    0.0932  4         True
4  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  4         True
5 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  4         False
6  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  3         True
7  1.023236  1.224234  7.823421  3         False
8 -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  3         False
9  23.23422  2.613492  2.341592  1         True
....
```

The data in `filename.dat` is saved such the the first row is considered to be the columns.

```
df.columns
```

outputs

```
Index(['0.098722', '08l23252', '243434214', '5', 'True'], dtype='object')
```

How do I add a row such that the current "columns" values row shifts down into the data table, and I could rename columns by actual column names?

At the moment, I cannot try

```
df.columns = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1']
```

as this simply erases this row and overwrites the values with `A1`, `B1`, etc.

```
   A1        B1        C1        D1        E1
1  0.283421  1.224234  7.823421  2         False
2 -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  4         False
3      2.34     0.271    0.0932  4         True
4  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  4         True
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
df = pd.read_table(data, names=['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'], header=None)
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html):

> **names** : array-like, default None
>
> List of column names to use. **If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None**

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter `names`:

```
df = pd.read_table(datan, names=['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'])
```

But it looks like better id use `read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
9,40  
1,70"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), names=['b','m'])
print (df)
   b   m
0  9  40
1  1  70
```